# Just an idea for skill set of each user

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page

I don't really know how Stack Overflow is built but I love it!! It's just a perfect tool for knowledge and problem solving.

Anyway, I have an idea, and I do not really know if it can be implemented.

The idea:

Each user can answer several questions, and each question owns a set of tags. So, what if these tags could be used to build the skill set of the user, and then promote his skills under his profile?

Of course this must be done with CRUD rules. For example, allow the user to add a set of tags in his profile as skills. So for example, let's say, in my profile I choose the following tags

```
WordPress
HTML
CSS
MySQL
Nuclear physics
```

and then I answer 5 questions with the tags WordPress, HTML. Another three questions with tags MySQL, HTML. Finally another 5 questions with tags HTML, CSS. Now my skill set should be something like this:

```
WordPress 5 Answers (19.23%)
HTML 13 Answers (50%)
CSS 5 Answers (19.23%)
MySQL 3 Answers (11.53%)
Nuclear physics 0 Answers (0 %)
```

or something similar. This will result in a skill set that seems to be near the real skill set of the user.

Comment: `I don't really know how the stackoverflow is build` For info check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Comment: We got exactly such thing: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Apart from Careers 2.0, this is already present in your profile. A quick look at your tags tells me you are active in PHP, Javascript, and HTML. Now go look at my profile and guess what my skillset consists of.

Comment: The problem with both your proposal and tags, is that *new* skillsets can take a long time to make an appearance in your profile, and depend not only on your ability to find an answer questions, but also on whom else is answering in that tag, and how many questions are being asked for a tag. My `django` tag is rather low still, but I do a lot more with Django these days than a year ago.

Comment: @Martin, looks like you're an expert in discussions and support! You're right, it does work (though it also suggests you are very good at creating bugs too).

Comment: @jmac *creating bugs* ... now those guys will just blame it on us ;)

Comment: Anyway, the community looks very friendly to me !! Thanks for that 6 downvotes ! You are the best ... !

Comment: @MerianosNikos, on meta votes are different. For a feature request downvotes just mean people don't agree with your idea, it's not about being unfriendly or your question being bad so don't take it personally.

Comment: @PeterJ, thanks for your information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haven't we already got this? This is [your Stack Overflow profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1150619/merianos-nikos), with the cursor hovered over the `65` of `php`:

[image]